# How to create a replica set enabled mongo service with Github Actions

Tags: mongodb, docker, github

I want to leverage Github Action's `service` and use it to create a mongo instance with **replica set** support.  This is what I have right now.

```
      mongo:
        image: mongo:5.0.3
        volumes:
          - /d/test-db.d
        ports:
          - 27017:27017 
        options: >-
          --entrypoint /usr/bin/docker run --name mongo_container --replSet test --bind_ip_all
          --health-cmd "bash -c \"if [ $(mongo mongo_container --quiet --eval 'rs.initiate().ok || rs.status().ok') -eq 1 ]; then exit 1; else exit 0; fi\""
          --health-interval 10s
          --health-timeout 5s
          --health-retries 5
          --name test
```

However, github actions gives me an error `'denied: requested access to the resource is denied'` when trying to call `docker run` as the entrypoint. I suppose it's not permittable for me to directly run docker run.

I also tried setting `--replSet test` and `--bind_ip_all` within the options array, but it is not recognized and throws and error.

I see nothing in the [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/create/#options) regarding replica sets. Are they even supported as a service?

Comment: Did you find a solution? Same question here.

Answer (score 0):

Judging by [this GH discussion](https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/26688), it appears its not possible to override the entrypoint with arguments. If you are able to forego the service container, you can solve your problem in a couple of ways.

### 1.  **Use [Supercharge](https://github.com/supercharge/mongodb-github-action)**

It provides a quick and simple way to setup your replica set and customise it somewhat using environment variables. The main drawback with this approach (which may or may not be relevant to you) is that you won't be able connect to the replica set *from* a service container because Supercharge [only listens on `localhost`](https://github.com/supercharge/mongodb-github-action/issues/52). If you don't need to connect from a service container and are happy with the additional dependency, then Supercharge will work great.

### 2. Docker run

If you are unable to use Supercharge for whatever reason or would like even more control over the configuration, you can easily spin up a single node replica set using `docker run` in a **step**:

```yaml
# ...some config omitted 
- name: Start mongo
    run:  docker run -d -p 27017:27017 --name mongo  mongo:6.0 --replSet test --bind_ip_all

  - name: Initialize MongoDB Replica Set
    run: |
      sleep 10
      docker run --rm mongo:6.0 mongosh --host 172.17.0.1 --eval 'rs.initiate({_id: "test", members: [{_id: 0, host: "172.17.0.1:27017"}]})'
# more steps
```

With this option, not only would you be able connect to the replica set using `localhost` from the host runner, you'd also be able connect from other service containers using the Docker bridge gateway address `172.17.0.1`